# Magento 2 Session is not working with cache on listing page

Tags: magento2

Session is not working with magento cache. On product listing page, If I change the limit 9 to 15 it's getting applied. And on other listing page it's setting the limit to 15 as expected. If I go back to previous page, limit is setting 9 instead of 15.

I have written the code as follows,

```
public function afterGetLimit()
{
    $limit = $this->getValue();

    //Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar

    if ($this->_toolbarModel->getLimit()) {
        return $this->_toolbarModel->getLimit();
        $this->setValue($this->_toolbarModel->getLimit());
    }
    else{
        return $this->getValue();
    }
}

public function setValue($key){
    //Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface
    $this->_session->start();
    $this->_session->setPerPageLimit($key);
}

public function getValue(){
    //Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface
    $this->_session->start();
    return $this->_session->getPerPageLimit();
}
```

I don't really understand what I'm missing. If I disable the cache it's working fine. How to handle this? I would want cache to be enabled.

Comment: A code you added to the question is in block file?

Comment: @MohitRane yes its in block file, [Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar

Comment: have you defined this block in the layout? if yes then add to the question

Comment: No, I didn't define. I have just overriden getLimit() method using my custom module.